# How to enable c++11 syntax highlighting in Qt Creator for CMake project

Tags: gcc, c++11, cmake, syntax-highlighting, qt-creator

How to enable C++11 syntax highlighting in Qt Creator for CMake project?

I have this code in CMakeLists.txt:

```
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
    add_definitions(-std=c++11)
endif()
```

Everything builds without any problem.

I know how to force Qt Creator to use C++ 11 syntax highlighting for qmake-based projects (set QMAKE_CXXFLAGS to -std=c++11 in *.pro file). Is there any similar solution for CMake?

Comment: Did you try `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++11 syntax highlighting should be enabled by default for CMake projects in very recent versions of QtCreator [2.7.0+](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator/qt-creator/blobs/2.7/dist/changes-2.7.0). In older versions just adding `-std=c++0x` to CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS should also work. To enable auto completion support for C++11 library features you may have to manually edit the generated cbp file and add the following under the compiler tag in the default target:

```
<Add option="-D__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__" />
```